# Writing data to arduino python

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino

I'm trying to write data from python to serial with this sketch

```
import serial
import smtplib
import time
s=serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-AH01LLHS',9600)
precx=500
ist=30
i=0
while True:
    s.write('1')
    stringa=s.readline()
    array=stringa.split(',')
    x=int(array[0])
    y=int(array[1])
    z=int(array[2])
    print(x,y,z)
    if(precx!=500):
        diffx=abs(x-precx)
        diffy=abs(y-precy)
        diffz=abs(z-precz)

        if((diffx>ist)|(diffy>ist)|(diffz>ist)):
            print('Ohu god',i)
            i+=1
            #time.sleep(2)
    precx=x
    precy=y
    precz=z
```

But when I execute the program I see nothing on the console, and the Arduino Rx led is off.

This is my Arduino sketch (nano atmega 328):

```
//Add the SPI library so we can communicate with the ADXL345 sensor
#include <SPI.h>

//Assign the Chip Select signal to pin 10.
int CS=10;

//This is a list of some of the registers available on the ADXL345.
//To learn more about these and the rest of the registers on the ADXL345, read the datasheet!
char POWER_CTL = 0x2D;  //Power Control Register
char DATA_FORMAT = 0x31;
char DATAX0 = 0x32; //X-Axis Data 0
char DATAX1 = 0x33; //X-Axis Data 1
char DATAY0 = 0x34; //Y-Axis Data 0
char DATAY1 = 0x35; //Y-Axis Data 1
char DATAZ0 = 0x36; //Z-Axis Data 0
char DATAZ1 = 0x37; //Z-Axis Data 1
//This buffer will hold values read from the ADXL345 registers.
char values[10];
//These variables will be used to hold the x,y and z axis accelerometer values.
int x,y,z;
boolean snd;
void setup(){ 
  //Initiate an SPI communication instance.
  SPI.begin();
  //Configure the SPI connection for the ADXL345.
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE3);
  //Create a serial connection to display the data on the terminal.
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Set up the Chip Select pin to be an output from the Arduino.
  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
  //Before communication starts, the Chip Select pin needs to be set high.
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);

  //Put the ADXL345 into +/- 4G range by writing the value 0x01 to the DATA_FORMAT register.
  writeRegister(DATA_FORMAT, 0x01);
  //Put the ADXL345 into Measurement Mode by writing 0x08 to the POWER_CTL register.
  writeRegister(POWER_CTL, 0x08);  //Measurement mode  
}

void loop(){
  //snd=true;
  //Reading 6 bytes of data starting at register DATAX0 will retrieve the x,y and z acceleration values from the ADXL345.
  //The results of the read operation will get stored to the values[] buffer.
  readRegister(DATAX0, 6, values);

  //The ADXL345 gives 10-bit acceleration values, but they are stored as bytes (8-bits). To get the full value, two bytes must be combined for each axis.
  //The X value is stored in values[0] and values[1].
  x = ((int)values[1]<<8)|(int)values[0];
  //The Y value is stored in values[2] and values[3].
  y = ((int)values[3]<<8)|(int)values[2];
  //The Z value is stored in values[4] and values[5].
  z = ((int)values[5]<<8)|(int)values[4];
 if (Serial.available() > 0) {
   if(Serial.read()=='1'){
     snd=true;
   }
   else{
     snd=false;
   }
 }
 if(snd){
  //Print the results to the terminal.
  Serial.print(x, DEC);
  Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(y, DEC);
  Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(z, DEC);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(10); 
 }

}

//This function will write a value to a register on the ADXL345.
//Parameters:
//  char registerAddress - The register to write a value to
//  char value - The value to be written to the specified register.
void writeRegister(char registerAddress, char value){
  //Set Chip Select pin low to signal the beginning of an SPI packet.
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  //Transfer the register address over SPI.
  SPI.transfer(registerAddress);
  //Transfer the desired register value over SPI.
  SPI.transfer(value);
  //Set the Chip Select pin high to signal the end of an SPI packet.
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
}

//This function will read a certain number of registers starting from a specified address and store their values in a buffer.
//Parameters:
//  char registerAddress - The register addresse to start the read sequence from.
//  int numBytes - The number of registers that should be read.
//  char * values - A pointer to a buffer where the results of the operation should be stored.
void readRegister(char registerAddress, int numBytes, char * values){
  //Since we're performing a read operation, the most significant bit of the register address should be set.
  char address = 0x80 | registerAddress;
  //If we're doing a multi-byte read, bit 6 needs to be set as well.
  if(numBytes > 1)address = address | 0x40;

  //Set the Chip select pin low to start an SPI packet.
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  //Transfer the starting register address that needs to be read.
  SPI.transfer(address);
  //Continue to read registers until we've read the number specified, storing the results to the input buffer.
  for(int i=0; i<numBytes; i++){
    values[i] = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  }
  //Set the Chips Select pin high to end the SPI packet.
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check if you can see anything with the serial monitor? That is: is it already clear if this is a python issue or a serial connection issue?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you tried a loopback test (connect RX and TX that comes out of the python-side)? You can also try having the arduino just constantly send data instead of waiting for the 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check the suggestions from the comments:

- make the program simpler so that it always sends values without "flow control" (using the "1" byte you send),
- use a serial monitor to check the output.

First, you shall check if you add a `s.flush()` before and after your `s.write('1')` helps. Then you may want to add `flush()` in your arduino code too.

To me it really looks like a starving issue at the initialization of your "flow control" algorithm. On the paper it looks good, but in real life, it may not. Very often, the Arduino sends a lot of garbage when it starts filling up the host serial port's buffer. And the other way around may be true. So instead of having a `1` on the arduino side, you may get a `!@#$@#%@#%!@#$` that's totally useless.

So on either side, before getting in the loops, you should add an init protocol. The arduino sends `READY`, the host sends `READY`, you flush out everything until you get `READY` on both sides. Something that would look like:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println('READY');
    Serial.flush();
    char ch1 = 0, ch2 = 0;
    char incomingByte = 0;
    while (ch1 != 'O' && ch2 != 'K') {
        ch1 = Serial.read();
        if (ch1 == 'O' && ch2 == 'K')
            break;
        ch2 = Serial.read();
    }
}
```

and on the python side:

```
with serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-AH01LLHS',9600) as s:
    s.flush()
    ready = ""
    while ready != "READY":
        ready = s.readline()
        s.flush()
    while True:
        # ... you stuff
```

of course that's only an idea of what you may do. You can make it more sophisticated, or way more simple. But before making such flow control, you really need to create a meeting point.